Inverse Series Expansion
I have a function $f(m)$, that satisfy:
$$
\frac{Q}{N}=f(m)
$$
Where $Q,N$ are some parameters.
My goal is to obtain an "inverse" function $m$ such that $m(\frac{Q}{N})= \sum_i c_i (\frac{Q}{N})^i$, so $m$ can be expanded in powers series of the original constant parameter.
For example,
$$
\frac{Q}{N}=\frac{\pi^2 m}{2}(m^2-\frac{1}{4})-\frac{\pi^4 m}{8}(m^2-\frac{1}{4})^2
$$
I don't know how to start to get the first order term at least.

You already asked this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4981360/).  Do not delete and repost a question which you have already asked.
